# Bootstrap dropdown only drops once

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap navbar:

```html
        <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="@Href("~")">Admin</a>
                        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="dropdown" id="accessList">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" id="accessListTopLink">Backend Options <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        }
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "ActionSelection", "View")</li>
                            @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                            {
                                <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="@Url.Action("LogOut", "User")">Log Out</a></li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then this script in the html file:

```js
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#accessList').one('click', function() {
                    LoadAccessList('@User.Identity.Name');
                });
                $('.accessList').on('click', function () {
                    alert('Hi');
                });
            });
        </script>
```

The LoadAccessList js function is:

```js
function LoadAccessList(email) {
    var dropDownControl = $('#accessList');
    var topLinkControl = $('#accessListTopLink');
    // Load the available access list options from the service
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            email: email
        },
        url: '../User/LoadAccessList',
        success: function(resultsList) {
            var htmlToAdd = '<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">';
            // Loop through and add all actions in.
            $.each($.parseJSON(resultsList), function(index, accessOption) {
                var serviceName = accessOption.Name;
                var url = accessOption.Url;

                htmlToAdd = htmlToAdd + '<li class="accessList"><a onclick="alert(\'Hi\')" href="' + url + '">' + serviceName + '</a></li>';
            });
            htmlToAdd = htmlToAdd + '</ul>';
            topLinkControl.after(htmlToAdd);
            dropDownControl.dropdown();
        },
        error: function(errorData) {
            // Error code passed back here.
            bootbox.alert('Error loading access list. Result was: <b>' + errorData.statusText + '</b>');
        }
    });
}
```

This ajax call basically loads a list of names and urls that will be added to the list to navigate to various sites.

I have 2 issues:

When I run the page and click the "Backend Options" it shows the dropdown list, but if I try to click any of the links I get the alert('Hi'), but it does not navigate to the link in the href.

Secondly, after the initial click of the dropdown then click away it no longer responds to another click so you cannot see the dropdown again.

Any help would be much appreciated as this is driving me mad!

**EDIT:**

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5wrn9r0/) link representing my issue.

Comment: What the .dropdown() function does exactly? Does it just show the content above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to change the following line:

```
dropDownControl.dropdown();
```

To this:

```
dropDownControl.show();
```